# how to pass object vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-spark

In My laravel + Spark + Vue js project, I have used https://github.com/Vanthink-UED/vue-core-image-upload, They have code like

```
export default {
props:{
 cropBtn: {
    type: Object,
    default: function() {
      return {
        ok: '保存',
        cancel: '取消',
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As per their documentationm, If you want to change button text then do following

> cropBtn  Object   {ok:'Save','cancel':'Give Up'}  the text of crop
>   button

I have used like

```
<vue-core-image-upload 
                      v-bind:class="['pure-button','pure-button-primary','js-btn-crop']" 
                      v-bind:crop="true" url="/process-image" 
                      extensions="png,gif,jpeg,jpg" 
                      cropBtn="[{ok: 'Save',cancel: 'Cancel'}]"                     
                      v-on:imageuploaded="imageuploaded">
                    </vue-core-image-upload>
```

and

```
v-bind:cropBtn="items"
```

js file

```
module.exports = {
prop:['cropBtn'],
data() {        
     return {
         items: [{
                    ok: 'Save',
                    cancel: 'Cancel',
                  }],
                  cropBtn: {
                            type: Object,
                            default: function() {
                              return {
                                ok: 'Save',
                                cancel: 'Cancel',
                              }
                            }
                          },

        src: 'http://img1.vued.vanthink.cn/vued0a233185b6027244f9d43e653227439a.png'            
    };
}
};
```

But it is not working. I am getting same default Chinese value.

Any suggestions what can be the solution?

Comment: i think it should be like :cropBtn="{ok: 'Save',cancel: 'Cancel'}" since you want to "v-bind" the prop and it expects an object - also you shouldnt add the cropBtn to your data return

Comment: I have tried but it did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `kebab-case` when passing `props` that are declared in camel case and you must use `v-bind` or the shorthand `:` when passing javascript objects through props:

```
<vue-core-image-upload :crop-btn="{ok: 'Save',cancel: 'Cancel'}"                     ></vue-core-image-upload>
```

see: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#camelCase-vs-kebab-case

Comment: This should be right, however I still think the data should'nt be an array. I'd also suggest @Jass you try to add Vue devtools to your chrome to make it more easy to identifiy such problems.

Comment: @FrankProvost Yes, I agree it looks like it should take an object, I'll update my answer.